# Unable to login due to Foreign key constraint between two tables

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, symfony-forms, symfony-4.2

I have two tables '**User**' and '**Address**', there is **OneToOne** relation between them as *User table has a column 'address_id' which stores 'id' of Address table*.

Here is the annotation in User Entity:

```
/**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\address", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $address;
```

**Security.yaml:**

```
security:
    encoders:
        App\Entity\User:
            algorithm: bcrypt

    providers:
        my_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: username
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            anonymous: true

            form_login:
                login_path: login
                check_path: login
                provider: my_provider
                default_target_path: dashboard

            logout:
                path: /logout
                target: /

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY  }
        - { path: ^/dashboard, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

**Controller:**

```
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationUtils;

class SecurityController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/login", name="login")
     */
    public function login(Request $request,AuthenticationUtils $utils)
    {
        // get the login error if there is one
        $error = $utils->getLastAuthenticationError();
        // dump($error);die;

        // last username entered by the user
        $lastUsername = $utils->getLastUsername();
        return $this->render('security/login.html.twig', [
            'last_username' => $lastUsername,
            'error' => $error
            ]);
    }

    public function logout()
    {
        # code...
    }   
}
```

I get this error when I insert my username and password:

> Authentication request could not be processed due to a system problem.

This is what I get when I dump() the error in controller.

> ```
> SecurityController.php on line 20:
> AuthenticationServiceException {#189 ▼
>   -token: UsernamePasswordToken {#236 ▶}
>   #message: "The target-entity App\Entity\address cannot be found in 'App\Entity\User#address'."
>   #code: 0
>   #file: "/home/users/kumar.saurabh/www/html/symfony/test-project/vendor/symfony/security-core/Authentication/Provider/DaoAuthenticationProvider.php"
>   #line: 85
>   trace: {▶}
> }
> ```

When I remove $address variables and its getter and setter function then the login is working fine, but when I am using this it gives me above mentioned error.

**How can I can achieve this by using Foreign key?** I am new to symfony, and I am learning on version 4.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beware the case, replace App\Entity\address by App\Entity\Address, update your schema and it should be fine

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\address", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $address;
```

should be

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Address", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $address;
```